# Crear acciones en aplicación Android con código QR

Tags: android, android-studio, qrcode, aplicación-movil, qr

Hola cómo va? Estoy pensando en realizar una aplicación Android, donde al leer un código de barras abra un formulario dentro de la misma aplicación.
Es posible esto?

Comment: Bienvenido, Julian, a Stack Overflow ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Tienes algún código? Por favor lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

SI es posible, por ejemplo puedes usar: [ZXing](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded)

En Java puedes llamar al lector de código así:

```
new IntentIntegrator(this).initiateScan()
```

O si lo quieres llamar cuando el usuarios presione un botón:

```
private IntentIntegrator qrScan; // 1.- define qrScan

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { // 2.- dentro de onCreate crea una nueva instancia de IntentIntegrator
    ...
    qrScan = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    ...
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    qrScan.initiateScan(); // 3.- llama el escaner cuando el usuario presiona el botón 
}
```

Una vez que el usuario escanee algo, tienes que recibir el evento así:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null) {
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
             Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

El resultado de lo escaneado estará en

```
result.getContents()
```

El resultado lo puedes parsear como JSONObject, así es más fácil de trabajar

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());
                textView1.setText(obj.getString("algo_1"));
                textView2.setText(obj.getString("algo_2"));
```

Espero sea de ayuda

Comment: esta genial, cual es la funcion para poder abrir automaticamente apenas el lector detecte algo?
saludos